# Detect when css is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building an AJAX-based website where all of website content is being loaded through AJAX.

Some pages have CSS that's being loaded along with content (code follows). Once the HTML and CSS is loaded I run a few scripts to change some image positions, alter width, and so on.

The problem is that sometimes my javascript gets executed *before* CSS rules get applied. For example: if my div width should be 200px according to the css, sometimes javascript reads it as 1000px, so I get wrong calculations.

My research has not yielded a cross-browser solution to detect not only loaded images but loaded CSS and everything else.

I use jQuery's AJAX function to get the desired HTML (this part is working fine). After I get the HTML I apply it with [**jQuery's html function**](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Once that's done I use this code to load required css:

```
css         = document.createElement('link');
css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
css.type    = 'text/css';
css.media   = "all";
css.href    = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
```

I *could* use a timeout function, but it would just be blind guessing, and I want to make sure my script runs when it needs to run. Any sugguestions?

**EDIT** I have included this image to make explanation clearer

[image]

Comment: would it be acceptable for you to just read and remove the `<style>` tags from the content you receive, before inserting into the DOM or you actually require some definitions?

Comment: @jAndy I'm not sure if i understand what you mean, I'm not using `<style>` tags, I am loading css from separate files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried before, but what about [Stylesheet load events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events)? In case IE won't fired the `onload` event, and you need to support it, `onreadystatechange` should works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to see I'm not the only one who has this problem.
I have some JavaScript which needs to be run AFTER the CSS styles are applied to the DOM.

I think what ZER0 suggested is a good solution, but I could not use the `OnLoad` event on my CSS `<link>` tag because I load a single concatenated/minified JS file at the *end* of the document, while my concatenated/minified CSS is at the *top* of the document.

**My solution:**
Put the essential CSS styles that the JavaScript depends on directly on the DOM using `<style>` tags.

This way, the styles get applied immediately when the DOM gets loaded. By the time JS is running, the DOM has the essential styles applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are over-complicating the problem. If you set all of your CSS up to only react to a certain parent class--eg: if you dynamically load the about page--all the CSS should look like `.about .example {} .about h2 {} etc`. The same would go for the contact page `.contact img {}`

Now, unless your CSS file is absolutely massive, if you include the one file at the top, you can pretty much guarantee that the CSS will be applied.

Comment: You did not understood my question, my css gets applied, the problem is that i load my css file when the website is already loaded, and when i load that css file i immediately call javascript function which needs css to be applied, but from what i have observed takes about 1-50ms so sometimes my javascript gets dimensions of elements before they get css applied therefore ruining my calculations

Comment: Why are you loading your CSS like this? I think you are over complicating your code. Sometimes simpler is normally better, less code and less things that can go wrong. There is no need to have to use JS to load a stylesheet. Simply in the head of your document, place it before the JS/jQuery sheets and it will load before your other libraries load.

Comment: I would have a very very big file, somwhere between 15k to 40k lines of code, and it would just keep on growing as the time goes because the website is huge, so it's difficult to work with that size of file and for users with slow connection would take to much time to download that file